# Vaadin version upgrade to 7.4.6 leads to a error "typeerror cannot read property 'noLayout' of undefined"

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, vaadin7

My Application was working fine with Vaadin version 7.3.6. Now i upgraded the version to 7.4.8 and my application is running into an issue, throws "typeerror cannot read property 'noLayout' of undefined".

I noticed that error message is visible only on Chrome browser but in IE11 and firefox I'm not able to see the error message, however problem persists in all the browsers.

Error Message :-

```
Fri Jun 19 11:05:56 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
SEVERE: Error updating connector statescom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'noLayout' of undefined
```

[image]

> > Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Handling type inheritance map from server
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO: Handling type mappings from server
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO: Handling resource dependencies
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Handling meta information
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Creating connectors (if needed)
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Updating connector states
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     SEVERE: Error updating connector statescom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'noLayout' of undefined
> >         at Unknown.Kbc(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.Abc(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.Lac(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.Jac(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.gnc(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.eval(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.HG(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.KG(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown.eval(com.xyz.na.myApp.application.widgetset.myAppWidgetset-0.js)
> >         at Unknown._f(http://localhost:19080/myApp/VAADIN/vaadinPush.debug.js?v=7.4.8)
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Handling locales
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Updating connector hierarchy
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Running @DelegateToWidget
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Sending state change events
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Passing UIDL to Vaadin 6 style connectors
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
> >     INFO:  * Performing server to client RPC calls
> >     Sun Jun 21 17:37:45 GMT+530 2015 com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection

I doubt that, noLayout exception is being thrown from the ***com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection*** class below code.

```
if (onlyNoLayoutUpdates) {
                                Profiler.enter("updateConnectorState @NoLayout handling");
                                for (String propertyName : stateJson.keys()) {
                                    Property property = stateType
                                            .getProperty(propertyName);
                                    if (!property.isNoLayout()) {
                                        onlyNoLayoutUpdates = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                Profiler.leave("updateConnectorState @NoLayout handling");
                            }
```

I'm continuously trying to debug the this code somehow so that I can be sure about the problem, but no luck yet. Do you have any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Vaadin debug window by addding ?debug to the URL and check there that both client and server are using the same Vaadin version. Most likely client side is still using version 7.3.6.

If you have your own Widgetset in use, you must recompile it to fix the problem.

Comment: I ran it in the debug mode and find out versions are same, but observed an error in generated script code of widgetSet. I'm attaching an screenshot for reference in the question itself.

Comment: What I can see in version is below:                                                                        Client engine version 7.4.6
Server engine version 7.4.6
Theme version 7.4.6
Push server version 2.2.4.vaadin5
Push client version 2.2.6.vaadin4-jquery (note: does not need to match server version)                              The push server version is different. Can it be a problem . If yes how can we fix it

Comment: @Abhishek-M Versions are correct, so that's not the problem. Do you use any addons / have your own client-side code on your project? Could u paste the stacktrace from browser's console, maybe that shows useful information.

Comment: @HenriKerola Whole stacktrace is too long to be pasted here, I copied the error and few near by lines from stack trace and added to the question itself. Please have a look.

Comment: @HenriKerola I've added few more details to the question itself, can you please help, if you've any clue about it. Thanks in advance.